Why hbase StoreFileSize (from jmx) and hdfs dfs -du -h are different?
i want to get the hbase table StoreFileSize,
but result of the command curl hostip:port/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=HBase,name=RegionServer,sub=Tables are different from hdfs dfs -du -h /hbase/data/default/tablename
i want to know the different means between StoreFileSize and 'hdfs dfs -du -h',and which one is table size?
